# How can I use \vfill in a lstlistings environment?

Tags: spacing, listings, vertical-alignment

I'd like to do something like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
public do(int whatever} {
\vfill
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

So basically, I want a method definition and then add spaces in the body of the method until the bottom of the page is reached. If possible I want to do that in one listing, since there are frames around my listings.

Comment: Do you use any special formatting of the `lstlisting` contents other than adding a frame? In that case, why not just format those elements manually and set a frame using something like [`tikzpagenodes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes)?

Comment: You have to ask listings to give you escape, then you can escape to latex and get the proper effect. escapeinside=XX, the X... X

Comment: @daleif That sounds like a good idea, and it works, however the frame is then not drawn correctly.

Comment: Can you add the code for the frame in your MWE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by escaping to LaTeX as daleif suggested and then change the `\vfill` into a `\leaders` so that the frame is drawn correctly:

[image: result of the code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{escapeinside=||}
\lstset{frameshape={RYRYNYYYY}{yny}{yny}{RYRYNYYYY},backgroundcolor=\color{blue!10}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
public do(int whatever} {
|\vspace{-1em}\parindent=0pt\par\leaders\vbox{\vrule height 0.5em depth 0pt width 0pt}\vfill\par\vspace{-1em}|
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! But defining a macro might be a good idea.